# Paste cell by cell into Word from Excel in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want, in Word VBA, to repeat copying content from Excel to Word.

Goal: I have a range in an Excel workbook about 250 cells long in column C that is a list of figure titles. I want to paste those titles into Word, as ‘captions’ (while leaving space to put the figures later, putting a consistent source caption on them, etc.)

I wrote code for one cell. I want to loop down to the next cell and insert a new caption with that new title, until all 250 distinct titles are entered.

Here is the code. I have it running a function, which runs a sub to get the title from one cell.

```
Sub Macro123()
Selection.InsertCaption Label:="Figure", TitleAutoText:="InsertCaption2", _
Title:=".", Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow, ExcludeLabel:=0
Selection.TypeText Text:=TitleDrop
Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("EcoCaption")
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeText Text:="Source: Current study, based off landings data from CDFW."
Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("EcoSource")
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeParagraph
End Sub
-----------
Function TitleDrop()
GetExcelTitles
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)

End Function
-----------------

Sub GetExcelTitles()
Dim ObjXL As Object, xlWkBk
Dim strTitleName As String

On Error Resume Next
Set ObjXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Excel Files are open (Excel is not running)"
    Exit Sub
End If
For Each xlWkBk In ObjXL.Workbooks
    If xlWkBk.Name = "130611 Figure Lists.xlsx" Then
        xlWkBk.Sheets("Figuresonly").Range("C6").Select
        xlWkBk.Sheets("Figuresonly").Range("C6").Copy
        Exit For
    End If
Next
Set ObjXL = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing some of your code to be like the following and make GetExcelTitles call your Paste Sub, not the other way around.

```
Dim rng as Range

For Each xlWkBk In ObjXL.Workbooks
If xlWkBk.Name = "130611 Figure Lists.xlsx" Then

For each xlWkBk.Sheets("Figuresonly").Range("C1", "C250")
  rng.Select
  rng.Copy
  Call TitleDrop
Next

End If
Next
```

Cheers, LC

Comment: Thank you! It really helped me to think of reordering the subs for GetExcelTitles to be the main one which called upon the other one.  I ended up with code that worked!